# AES CTR OpenSSL command line does not match EVP_aes_128_ctr C code

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, encryption-symmetric

[CTR-AES256 Encrypt does not match OpenSSL -aes-256-ctr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847568/ctr-aes256-encrypt-does-not-match-openssl-aes-256-ctr)  <-- this post did not help

I tried the following C implementation of Openssl EVP function for AES-128-CTR encryption but the results I am getting are incorrect compared to the command line OpenSSL result.

**The odd part is that when I try with a larger size of Plaintext (600 bytes or more), only last 600 bytes of cipher is different between C code and Command line. If required I can paste that result here as well.**

C code implementation of AES-128-CTR

```
static const unsigned char key[16] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 
    0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 
    0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 
};

static const unsigned char iv[16] = {
    0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 
    0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 
    0x88, 0x88, 0x88, 0x88, 
    0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
};

FILE *fp_output = fopen("cipherCode.bin", "wb");

// Encrypt Plaintext

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
int outlen;
unsigned char cipher[size];

if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

if(!(EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ctr(), NULL, key, iv))) handleErrors();

if(!(EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, cipher, &outlen, plaintext, size))) handleErrors();

if(!(EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, cipher + outlen, &outlen))) handleErrors();

/*---Edit----

// EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0); <-- removed this as it isnt necessary 

-----------*/

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

// Write result cipher into output file
fwrite((unsigned char *)&cipher[0], outlen, 1, fp_output);
fclose(fp_output);
```

OpenSSL command line:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -in plaintext.bin -out cipherCL.bin -K 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -iv 0123456789abcdef88888888c0000000 -p -nopad
```

Same Plaintext, key and IV used for both.

Input:

```
Plaintext:

0000000 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
```

Ouput:

Hexdiff (shortened for clarity):

```
Visuel HexDiff v 0.0.53 by tTh 2007                             dec   7bits  

0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 90 66 01 00 00 00 00              f     

** cipherCode.bin                                    16        0   0%      

0   1e a4 43 3f d8 4c 8c b7 1a e7 f0 af 85 0c d2 c2      C? L

** cipherCL.bin                                   16        0   0%
```

Comment: Include in your code excerpt how you are declaring `key` and `iv`.

Comment: Also show how your code writes the output file; a 'ciphertext' having three-quarters of its bytes zero is effectively impossible. FYI calling `_set_padding` after doing encryption (or decryption) is useless, but CTR is a stream mode and doesn't use padding anyway.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark  _dave_thompson_085_ Please check the edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my program. I was not defining the cipher variable as static. Now that I define it static, the correct cipher data is written to the file.

**Why static worked?**
I called a ciphering function to calculate the cipher and then return the cipher. Since the cipher was not declared as *static*, it lost its value after exiting the function, thus the data returned was not the same as the data in the cipher. After declaring cipher as *static*, the value of cipher retained after function call and wrote correct information in the file.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use this free AES library
[link](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c)

It's small and portable implementation of AES ECB, CTR and CBC encryption algorithms written in c. It contains everything you need, and it's very simple.
Btw you can override the default key-size of 128 bit with 192 or 256 bit by defining the symbols AES192 or AES256 in `aes.h`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.